# Classifying SSL/TLS vulnerabilities

Tags: tls, openssl

I'm currently working on a school project, which is a tool that generate security auditing reports in PDF.
I'm using testssl.sh which check for following SSL/TLS vulnerabilities:

- Heartbleed
- CCS Injection
- Secure Renegotiation
- Secure Client-Initiated Renegotiation
- CRIME
- BREACH
- POODLE SSL
- Downgrade attack (TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV)
- SWEET32
- FREAK
- DROWN
- LOGJAM
- BEAST
- LUCKY13
- RC4

I want to classify them into differents risk levels (High, Medium, Low) and whether a vulnerability can be exploited in real life.

Thank you

**EDIT**
I made this table a few days ago, and according to the CVSS v2 scoring system, the majority of the vulnerabilities severity are Medium, and many vulnerabilities share the same scores.
I got confused on how to rate these vulnerabilities based on Impact/Exploitability and whether a vulnerability is a real threat.
[image]
To better explain my need, when a vulnerability is identified, I want to indicate to the user how much important the threat is to confidentiality and how easy it is to exploit.

Comment: In the current form the question is too broad. Please start with classifying into risk levels yourself and if you run into specific problems while doing this and cannot find answers to these problems then you can ask for help on these specific problems, but only one per question.

Comment: Its also unclear what you're asking. For reference you can take the [Red Hat severity ratings](https://access.redhat.com/security/updates/classification) as a starting point

Comment: The question is better now, I voted to reopen. Anyway, I'd put a clear problem statement, maybe even formulated as a real question at the very bottom of your post.